# How do I import a PostgreSQL table into d3 for use?

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, d3.js

I am currently using d3.csv to import a table for use in a graph, however, I instead want to use a table from my Postgres database. I have the database connected to Django however I am unsure what d3 function I can use to fetch a table from the database and use it instead of a CSV file.

```
     d3.csv("[link]", function(data) {
        console.log(data);
```

Console.log(data) returns a table that looks like this:

Here is the screenshot:

[image: IMG]

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself, basically what I did was in views.py
`return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', myData), safe=False)`
Where myData = (model).objects.all()

Then all I had to do was parse the data in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies, but Postgres provides a lot of tools for formatting data before the return. For example, here's a simple example based on a table called "mockit" that I've got some sample data in:

```
SELECT row_to_json(mockit_row) AS mockit_objects
FROM
      (SELECT   first_name, last_name, email
       FROM     mockit
       WHERE    gender = 'Male'
       LIMIT 10) AS mockit_row;
```

What you get is one object per row, as a JSON object

```
{"first_name":"Farlay","last_name":"Creegan","email":"fcreegan0@github.io"}
{"first_name":"Holt","last_name":"Cicco","email":"hcicco1@scribd.com"}
```

etc.

If you want a single JSON object with an array of objects:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(mockit_row))) AS mockit_objects
FROM
      (SELECT   first_name, last_name, email
       FROM     mockit
         WHERE  gender = 'Male'
       LIMIT 10) AS mockit_row;
```

D3 (I miss working with D3) dehydrates things into arrays of objects, as I recall. So you can provide the data in the format, if it's easier. CSV and TSV are smaller wire formats, but I don't think (?) there's currently support for output results to that format within Postgres as a SQL call.

Postgres is *crazy fast*, so it's good to push processing up to it.